# How to get list of classes belonging to a specific namespace from inside the Symfony Kernel?

Tags: php, symfony, enums

Using Symfony 6.2

I have few enums inside `App\Entity\Enum` namespace (`src/Entity/Enum` folder). I need to get list of all these enums from inside my `Kernel::process()` function:

```php
class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        // get the list of enums from App\Entity\Enum namespace
    }
```

I would prefer to be able to find the class (enum) names through the namespace.

My initial idea was to use `services.yaml`

```yaml
services:
    _instanceof:
        BackedEnum:
            tags: [ 'app.tagged_enum' ]
```

But enums are never tagged.

I tried also this kernel function:

```php
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
{
    $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(\BackedEnum::class)
        ->addTag('app.tagged_enum')
    ;
}
```

which also did not work.

If I then try to get the list inside `Kernel::process()` I get an empty array:

```php
$taggedEnums = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.tagged_enum');
```

Comment: I have not tried this myself but since enums can implement interfaces you might consider making an empty EnumInterface and then tagging it.  The syntax seems strange but the docs show an example for backed enums like `enum Status: string implements HasColor`

Comment: Of course enums are not classes so I am not sure if they even show up as services through autowire.  debug:container would let you know pretty quickly.

Comment: @Cerad yes, the issue is that enums are not treated as services, this is why even with dummy interface the instanceof check fails and they are never tagged. I opened a RFC https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/48699 . Even if this gets support, until then, do you have any idea how to list all enums inside some namespace? Id like to avoid having to use scandir and open recursively all files in the project to build the list of used enums.

Comment: The `src/Entity` directory is excluded in the standard `services.yaml` file. So, that may be the beginning of your issue. But I guess a bigger question is _why_ are you trying to make this list? perhaps there is a better way to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @michnovka Symfony's file component has some utilities for find all file in a directory so I suppose you could start there.  Good to know that enums are not services.

Comment: @craigh yes, it is indeed excluded, but I moved it to another dir and still it is not tagged. The reason is as I mentioned that enums are not treated as services, and tagging works only with services. As for why - I need to register custom DBAL types for every enum. I want as little boilerplate code as possible, and for that I need to be able to list all enums in some namespace (dir). I can then check e.g. their attribute, assign it some AutoconfigureDBALType attribute or whatever to decide which enums are to be used. But the step 1 is to get an actual list of all enums inside some namespace